# Unable to catch Exception when using Eval function

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm writing code that randomly generates expressions for a genetic algorithm for code optimisation purposes. The generated expressions are `eval`'ed for fitness. Some expressions will generate errors and I need to be able to catch these and act appropriately.

I have the following code (simplified from the original):

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
});

$expression = '$y=~!7;';

try {
    eval($expression);
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo 'Expression failed';
} catch (ParseError $e){
    echo 'Expression failed';
}
```

This throws the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Unsupported operand types in ..... : eval()'d code on line ....
```

But this error is **not** caught in either `catch` block.

I've set my own error handler so that all errors are promoted to exceptions.

How do I catch this error?

**Note**: I am very aware that using `eval` is dangerous, but there is *strictly* no user input in my code.

Comment: From the manual about [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php): _"The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called."_

Comment: A parse error would be caught by: catch (ParseError $e). That doesn't work either. And the error is not a parse error?

Comment: Why do you not write an external file and execute that using the PHP interpreter, making sure a user account is used that has no write rights anywhere?  I would say that code generated by a genetic algorithm can be even more dangerous than code from user input.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of the danger of using `eval`. The expressions I'm generating are short simple arithmetical/logic expressions, nothing more complicated. I just need  a straightforward way to check if they are valid.

Answer (score 0):

At least in PHP 7.1+, eval() terminates the script if the evaluated code generate a fatal error. For example:

```
@eval('$content = (100 - );');
```

(Even if it is in the man, I'm note sure it acted like this in 5.6, but whatever)
To catch it, I had to do:

```
try {
    eval('$content = (100 - );');
} catch (ParseError $e) {
    $content = null;
}
```

This is the only way I found to catch the error and hide the fact there was one.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think the error is a parse error and so is not caught by the try-catch.

Comment: what php version are you using?

Comment: My version is PHP 7.4

Comment: php 7.1+ eval() terminates the script if the evaluated code generate a fatal error. as my first line said of the post.